# Where can I download a database (for data visualization)?

Tags: database, d3.js, data-visualization

I wish to acquire a (free, downloadable, excel) DB of 500 to 1,000 records that consist of >= 10 attributes to display meaningful relationships in a data visualization diagram via D3.js, alike http://www.flickr.com/photos/michaellevi/3349638282/

The topic does not matter, as long as the above is fulfilled. Can anyone please point me to the right direction? Been looking around across topics medical, finance, automobiles, academics, statistics etc but none offered what I need.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples

Comment: Thank you but i just found one. helpful!